# How to set hidden property of a file with python

Tags: python

I am using ctypes to try and set a file to hidden but when i run the code, it seems to just make the hidden button become unclickable and the file is still not hidden.  How do i fix this?

```
filepath='file path'
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(unicode(file2path),'FILE_ATTRIBTE_HIDDEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of SetFileAttributesW should be a code to set the value

Try this

```
HIDE_ATTRIBUTE = 0x02
filepath='file path'
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(unicode(file2path), HIDE_ATTRIBUTE)
```